# Wordcloud centralize and reduce overlap in randomly positioned words inside a plot

Tags: python, random, plotly

```
import plotly
import random
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots   

random.seed(42) 

words = ['potato','hello','juvi']
colors = [plotly.colors.DEFAULT_PLOTLY_COLORS[random.randrange(1, 10)] for i in range(20)]
weights = [110,80,20]

data = go.Scatter(x=[random.random() for i in range(20)],
             y=[random.random() for i in range(20)],
             mode='text',
             text=words,
             marker={'opacity': 0.3},
             textfont={'size': weights,
                       'color': colors})

layout = go.Layout({'xaxis': {'showgrid': False, 'showticklabels': False, 'zeroline': False},
                'yaxis': {'showgrid': False, 'showticklabels': False, 'zeroline': False}})
fig = go.Figure(data=[data], layout=layout)

fig.show()
```

I have the following sample code which generates a wordcloud in plotly, the thing is as you can see the words tend to get out of the given square in the plot any ideas on how I could keep the words inside the blueish square. Or at least more to the center of it

[image]

Comment: nit: for reproducibility, you might consider setting a seed

Comment: your code generates a word cloud but will only have three words plotted at the location of the first three coordinates passed to x and y. is this the intended behavior?

Comment: Forgot to update on the given sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occurring because you're passing 20 randomly generated (x,y) coordinates to `go.Scatter`, but only 3 words total, so plotly is setting the default axis ranges based on the coordinates you're passing and not the location of the 3 words.

If that was not intentional, then I would assume you meant to plot 20 randomly selected words from your list at the 20 coordinates, and you would modify your code like this:

```
import plotly
import random
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots   

random.seed(42) 

words = ['potato','hello','juvi']
colors = [plotly.colors.DEFAULT_PLOTLY_COLORS[random.randrange(1, 10)] for i in range(20)]
weights = [110,80,20]

x = [random.random() for i in range(20)]
y = [random.random() for i in range(20)]
scatter_words = [random.choice(words) for i in range(20)]
scatter_weights = [random.choice(weights) for i in range(20)]
data = go.Scatter(x=x,
             y=y,
             mode='text',
             text=scatter_words,
             marker={'opacity': 0.3},
             textfont={'size': scatter_weights,
                       'color': colors})

layout = go.Layout({'xaxis': {'showgrid': False, 'showticklabels': False, 'zeroline': False},
                'yaxis': {'showgrid': False, 'showticklabels': False, 'zeroline': False}})
fig = go.Figure(data=[data], layout=layout)

fig.show()
```

[image]